# Create an instance of a class N times without assigning it to a variable

Tags: python, cpython

CPython 3.8

```
class Class: pass

s = set(
    id(Class())
    for _ in range(5)
)
len(s) == 1  # True
```

Seems like it's an interpreter magic that definitely has something to do with garbage collection. Is it CPython specific, not guaranteed by any standard behavior?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? The behavior of id and memory management is entirely implementation specific.

Comment: The short answer to your questions are YES and YES.  It has something to do with garbage collection, and it is an implementation dependent behavior.  To address what the title of you question implies...the object IS stored, but then that storage is immediately given up when the lifetime of the object quickly ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given two distinct objects `x` and `y` (i.e., `x is y` is false), `id(x) != id(y)` is only guaranteed if the life times of `x` and `y` overlap. If they do not overlap (as is the case here), neither `id(x) == id(y)` or `id(x) != id(y)` is required to be true. One or the other *will* be, based on the implementation, but neither is more or less "correct" than the other.

Comment: Yes. I was going to say the same thing.  If you retain the objects themselves in the set, then they have unique ids, as their lifetimes then extend beyond the loop iteration in which they are created.

Comment: Reference: [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) *"... This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value."*